# Asp.net Identity + Identity is not maintaining in subsequent request

Tags: asp.net-identity, identity, persistent

I am trying to implement Asp.net Identity in my web (MVC5) application. In User Authentication method I am authenticating user, if user exist then I am manually creating Claims Identity and Principal in my application  (Authentication.cs). After that I am assigning the Claims Principal to current HttpContext and Thread.  So now I am able to see  Identity in the same request httpcontext. But if I am trying to access Claims Identity from different action/page then it will show a null values in the User.Identity object, that is, Identity is not maintaing in the subsequent request.

In my application I set AuthenticationMode="None" in web.config so I removed LoginPath attribute from OWIN Startup class.

I am not sure what I missed here, please help me to fix this issue.

```
//OWIN startup.cs
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Web.Startup))]
namespace Web
{

public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // For more information on how to configure your application, 
visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=316888
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Always
        });

    }
}
}


//Authentication.cs
//After user authentication, setting Thread and http context.
if (user != null)
{
var authenticationManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;

var claims = new List<Claim>();
claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "username"));
claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, "username@gmail.com"));
var userIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

ClaimsPrincipal principal2 = new ClaimsPrincipal(userIdentity);

authenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = false }, userIdentity);

var test = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated; //return false


HttpContext.Current.User = principal2;

test = userIdentity.IsAuthenticated; // User Identity is authenticated return true
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal2;
test = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated; //return true
```

}

But if I redirect to different page/action then the values in User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is displaying as false.

Thanks
Selvakumar

Answer (score 0):

The `IsPersistent` property is specifically for [determining whether to persist authentication across multiple requests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.authenticationproperties.ispersistent(v=vs.113).aspx). Set it to `true`.